# How load an image from disk and save to a stream using ImageSharp while preserving the mimetype

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imagesharp

I've got a bunch of images stored on disk, with the mimetype of the image stored in a database. If I want to save the image to disk I can use [`Image.Save(string)`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.ImageExtensions.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_ImageExtensions_Save_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_System_String_) (or the Async version) without needing to know the MimeType of the image.

However, if I want to save to a stream (for example, `Response.Body`) then I have to use [`Image.Save(Stream, IImageEncoder)`](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.ImageExtensions.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_ImageExtensions_Save_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_System_IO_Stream_SixLabors_ImageSharp_Formats_IImageFormat_).

How do I get the `IImageEncoder` I need to save to the stream (without just declaring that "All my images ar png/jpeg/bmp" and using e.g. `JpegEncoder`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ImageSharp can already tell you the mimetype of the input image. With your code if the
mimetype doesn't match the input stream then the decode will fail.

```cs
(Image Image, IImageFormat Format) imf = await Image.LoadWithFormatAsync(file.OnDiskFilename);

using Image img = imf.Image;
img.Save(Response.Body, imf.Format);
```

What we are [missing](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/1334) however in the current API v1.0.1 is the ability to save asynchronously while passing the format. We need to add that.

Comment: I already know the media type of the image on disk (its in the db with the filename) so I don't need to discover it, I just need to get an decoder/encoder pair so I can load/save the image.

Comment: And if it's ever wrong?... 

With the approach I'm suggesting, you don't even need to store it (unless you need it elsewhere). All the methods you are calling to discover the encoder to use are called by the overload anyway. Trust me, I own the library.

Comment: You've convinced me :)

Comment: You are not using dispose on `Image` here.

Comment: Yes I am via the `using` declaration. `using Image img = imf.Image;`

Comment: If you don't have a stream: `using (var stream = File.OpenRead(stringPath))`

Comment: @Cryptc You don't need to do that. You can load using the path directly.

Comment: @JamesSouth I believe it depends what version of ImageSharp you have installed.

Comment: It doesn’t. That’s been supported since v1. (It’s my software)

Answer (score 6):

ImageSharp 3.0 changed the API.  `LoadWithFormatAsync` doesn't exist any more.  The new way is:

```
using var img = await Image.LoadAsync(file.OnDiskFilename);
await img.SaveAsync(Response.Body, img.Metadata.DecodedImageFormat!);
```

Answer (score 4):

It took a bit of messing about, but I've figured it out:

```
var file = ... // From DB

ImageFormatManager ifm = Configuration.Default.ImageFormatsManager;
IImageFormat format = ifm.FindFormatByMimeType(file.MimeType);
IImageDecoder decoder = ifm.FindDecoder(format);
IImageEncoder encoder = ifm.FindEncoder(format);

using Image img = await Image.LoadAsync(file.OnDiskFilename, decoder); 
// Do what you want with the Image, e.g.: img.Mutate(i => i.Resize(width.Value, height.Value)); 
Response.ContentType = format.DefaultMimeType; // In case the stored mimetype was something weird 

await img.SaveAsync(Response.Body, encoder);
```

(Although I'm happy to be shown a better way)

Comment: This looks like its for use in generate thumbnails or equivalent. You might want to rethink returning the original file format, after you have mutated it, at all... You are probably never going to want to resize a bmp and then return it in bmp format for example, in that case you would always want a nice compressed jpeg or png.

Comment: Maybe, although looking at my current data set I've got about 1500 jpegs and 6 pngs, and nothing else (and I don't want to be saving my pngs as jpegs, or vice versa)